# Query regarding LACP timeout flag

Tags: switching, layer2, ieee-802.1ax

Say we have two swicthes.
Switch A and Switch B.

```
Switch A sends LACPDU's with timeput flag set to 1 (fast).
Switch B sends LACPDU's with timeout flag set to 0 (slow).
```

By researching came to know that the switch advertises this as that it is expecting the neighbour to honor it.

I want to understand how this works here.

Is it like by some means both of them negotiate which timeout to use ?
Like both sides use fast or slow.
If yes, based on what do they identify.

Or is it like the sides continue to use their respective speed.

Like Switch A expects that LACPDU comes every 1 second and Switch B sends it.
And Switch B expects that LACPDU come every 30s and Switch A sends it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short vs long timeout expresses preference for LACPDU timeout - it's not negotiated. Each side sends LACPDUs *according to its partner's* timeout preference.

See 802.1AX Clause 6.4.1:

> d) Periodic transmission of LACPDUs occurs if the LACP_Activity
> control of either the Actor or the Partner is Active LACP. These
> periodic transmissions will occur at either a slow or fast
> transmission rate depending upon the expressed LACP_Timeout preference
> (Long Timeout or Short Timeout) of the Partner System.